# Dot product of two vectors multiplied by same real number.

Tags: vectors

I recently read a formula for dot product of two vectors in my course book. 
Let there be two vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

It stated that   $$c\vec{a} \cdot c\vec{b} = c(\vec{a} \cdot\vec{b})$$

I'm really confused why the real number isn't squared in the RHS. According to my understanding of multiplication, the RHS should look like   $c^2(\vec{a} \cdot\vec{b})$. 
Am I making some big blunder here or maybe there is a printing/typing mistake in the book i'm referring to?

Comment: You are correct, and there is a printing/typing mistake in the book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot product is *bilinear*, meaning that for all $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
 x \cdot (y+z) = x \cdot y + x \cdot z, \\
 (x+y) \cdot z = x \cdot z + y \cdot z, \\
 (\lambda x) \cdot y = \lambda (x \cdot y) = x \cdot (\lambda y).
$$
From the last equality it follows that for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
 (ca) \cdot (cb)
= c (a \cdot (cb))
= c^2 (a \cdot b),
$$
so you are right.

Comment: The book is a very reputed one used by more than half the schools here and in my last 5 years with it i had never encountered a typo so i had to confirm it here before marking it as a typo and your steps loook really sound to me so i would take is at a typo. Thank you very much.